# is poll-based Gmail sync better than Cloud Pub/Sub?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

In the [guide document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) under "Push notifications > Overview > Note," it seems that Pub/Sub is not recommended for user-owned devices. There might be reasons for this recommendation. why do they recommend poll-based synchronization?

for real time synchronization